# Not able to download certificate using intune company portal

Tags: intune

I have company provided Samsung S20. I have successfully installed Microsoft's Intune Company Portal App.
Then I was also able to register company portal. However after connecting to company portal, it suppose to download certificate from the company portal. But its not downloading any certificate or i dont see any notifications that it is downloaded.

Once i have the certificate, i will use it to connect to Access Point. But that's next step after i have the certificate.

1>What could be the potential issue for not downloading certificate?
2>Where and how can i view the logs?
3>In Company Portal App, Under settings i see Diagnostic Data-> Copy logs. Which says Copy logs to SD card. Where does it actually copies logs.
4>I am connecting from home. Is there any settings i need to do on router.

Note that, I also have company provided iPhone. and I was able to install and configure everything without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

1>What could be the potential issue for not downloading certificate?

- It depends on what you need the certificate for. How are you issuing the certificate to the device? via configuration policy?

2>Where and how can i view the logs?

- Plug the device into a computer and allow USB to transfer data and files. Should be under Android\Com.microsoftintunecompanyportal\data

3>In Company Portal App, Under settings i see Diagnostic Data-> Copy logs. Which says Copy logs to SD card. Where does it actually copies logs.

- refer to previous answer

4>I am connecting from home. Is there any settings i need to do on router.

- Sounds like you're trying to get a trust certificate on the device but I would need to understand more about what you're trying to do. RIght now I'm working on a wifi profile for android devices and am using SCEP certificates to do that. But you're welcome to read this to try to gain a better understanding.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/protect/certificates-configure